# Separating string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

### The goal

`99999999` to `9999 9999`.

### The problem

I searched for [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), but I couldn't apply. I don't want to separate the string into two variables, I just want to separate the string to displaying proposals.

### The scenario

There is the following fragment on my application:

```
var contactPhone = "91929394";
```

And I want to separate `91929394` into `9192 9394` by calling the same variable (`contactPhone`).

### Clarifying know-how questions

I really don't know the syntax, even not how I have to search for. Take it easy — it is a programming question.

Comment: That should be a string, not a number.

Comment: That's a number, not a string. How are you displaying it?

Comment: Do you always want to split into blocks of 4 digits?

Comment: Guys, my bad. I already changed for `integer`. And @MatthewRiches,  I don't understand your question.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge: Phone numbers are not integers.  If you can't add it, it isn't a number.  You should only use strings.

Comment: @SLaks The phone numbers on my database are `CHAR(8)`. My mistake was by expression — sorry for this.

Comment: He's asking whether phone numbers should always be displayed in `xxxx xxxx xxxx` format, regardless of phone number length.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy In my country, more specifically on my state, our phone format is always the same: xxxx xxxx. Then, isn't a necessity to *always* format the phone by each four numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `contactPhone.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{4})/, '$1 $2')`

It will split the phone number into two groups, with 4 digits each.

If `contactPhone` is a number and not a string, you can use `contactPhone.toString()` before using the regex replace.

Comment: Hello, @dcro. Your answer is concisely and clear — thank you! And about the confusion about the type of my variable, don't worry because was my mistake. I've expressed myself badly.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply;

```
var formatted = contactPhone.toString();
formatted = formatted.substr(0, 4) + " " + formatted.substr(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function sep(str){
    var len = str.length;
    var a = len/2;
    return str.substring(0, a) + ' ' + str.substring(a, len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to be more robust, you could add a space after every 4th character?

```
contactPhone.replace(/.{1,4}/g, '$& ');
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this help?

```
function splitInTwo(s){
    return [s.substring(0, s.length/2), s.substring(s.length/2)]
}
```